# spring hibernate upgrade issues

Tags: spring, hibernate, upgrade

In our project we are trying to migrate spring+ hibernate from

```
<spring.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>3.0.8.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
<hibernate.version>3.3.0.GA</hibernate.version>
```

to

```xml
<spring.version>5.3.31</spring.version
<spring.security.version>5.8.9</spring.security.version>
<hibernate.version>5.6.15.Final</hibernate.version>
```

I am facing issue while deploying in Jboss server

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EhcacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource \[/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml\]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate \[net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager\]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:*

1. *Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary*
2. *Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.*

   *The source of the existing CacheManager is: InputStreamConfigurationSource \[stream=java.io.FileInputStream@4c572339\]*
   *service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./repository: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key \[0\]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3f48e503' of type \[org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter\] while setting*
```

Comment: I tried changing in  applicationContext-hibernate.xml following from<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop> to   <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
       <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>

Comment: don't add info via comments to the question. Edit the question instead.